# How to pass all selected files in Dolphin as parameters for Desktop Entry?

Tags: linux, dolphin-file-manager

I’m trying to port a Nemo script to Dolphin actions.

The script shows a slideshow of the files or folders selected, but when I call the action from Dolphin it makes a call to the script for each file selected instead of once.

This is my desktop entry code:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin,inode/directory,image/*
ExcludeServiceTypes=kdedevice/*
Encoding=UTF-8
Actions=slideshow;shuffled_slideshow
SingleMainWindow=true

[Desktop Action slideshow]
Name=Slideshow
Icon=image
Exec=/home/user/.local/share/nemo/scripts/slideshow.sh

[Desktop Action shuffled_slideshow]
Name=Shuffled Slideshow
Icon=image
Exec=/home/user/.local/share/nemo/scripts/shuffled_slideshow.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112497/kde-service-menus-get-list-of-selected-files

I just had to add an ¨%F¨ parameter at the end of Exec

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin,inode/directory,image/*
ExcludeServiceTypes=kdedevice/*
Encoding=UTF-8
Actions=slideshow;shuffled_slideshow
SingleMainWindow=true

[Desktop Action slideshow]
Name=Slideshow
Icon=image
Exec=/home/user/.local/share/nemo/scripts/slideshow.sh  %F

[Desktop Action shuffled_slideshow]
Name=Shuffled Slideshow
Icon=image
Exec=/home/user/.local/share/nemo/scripts/shuffled_slideshow.sh %F
```